# react-native-audio-toolkit, isPlaying is not working

Tags: react-native

```
import React from "react";
import { Player } from "@react-native-community/audio-toolkit"; 


export default class RNAudiotoolkit extends React.Component {
componentDidMount(){
    new Player("some_audio_file.mp3").play();
    console.log(Player.isPlaying);
}
}
```

Above is the minimum code I've whittled down to, the audio track does play but, console.log(Player.isPlaying) always returns "false" but the audio file is running.  Any input on why this isn't working. I can only suspect it has something to do with MediaStates, but have unsuccessfully gotten anything to work.  If you have experience with this package your input is greatly appreciated.

documentation: https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-audio-toolkit/blob/master/docs/API.md

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit:** Fixed and tested; answer is a combination of my original and mAhMoUdDaFeR's answer.

If you look above the documentation for the `play` method, you will see the documentation for `prepare(Function callback)`. In it, it states:

> ...Otherwise the file is prepared when calling play() **which may result in a small delay**.

This means that if you check the `.isPlaying` property immediately after calling `play()` like you are doing, it is not guaranteed that the file is actually playing by time your `console.log(Player.isPlaying)` executes.

There is also the second issue that `.isPlaying` is not a static property on the `Player` class despite how it appears in the docs. It is actually a property of the `Player` instance that you need to create to play an audio file.

If you want to see that `.isPlaying` is indeed working correctly, one potential check is to run your code in a callback function passed into `.play()` as the docs show:

> `play(Function ?callback)`
>
> Start playback.
>
> If callback is given, it is called when playback has started.

So a simple example would be to write your example code like this (saving the created instance and then logging in a callback):

```
componentDidMount(){
    const p = new Player("some_audio_file.mp3").play(() => console.log('in callback', p.isPlaying));
    console.log('immediately after play', p.isPlaying);
}
```

I created a new project to test this and if you run the above code, you'll see the following printed out illustrating the issue:

```
immediately after play false
in callback true
```

Comment: Great! btw, I am currently having a weird issue with RN-audio-toolkit on iOS .. it stops playing in random places and wondering if you have faced the issue before ?

Comment: @Aung Myint Thein faced it with android as well

Answer (score 3):

`isPlaying` is not a static method in the component Player, so you can't use `Player.isPlaying`, you can get `isPlaying` from the created instance (object) of this Player.

Try keeping a reference of the player object and then accessing its children:

`this.player = new Player("some_audio_file.mp3").play()`

and then log:

`console.log(this.player.isPlaying)`